# Bin Packing issue with constrains in R for genomic data

Tags: r, random, bin-packing

I'm trying to solve a different version of the bin packing problem in R. Any insights or resources will be appreciated.

I'm trying to randomize finite amount of items (windows) in all the bins (chromosomes), but there regions in each chromosome that cannot be used.

Example for the data I have:

Chromosomes length:

```
Chr1:1 - 200000
chr2:1 - 100000
.
.
.
```

Constrains:

```
chr1: 100-200
chr1: 5000-5087
chr2: 1098-2067
.
.
.
```

The items size I need to pack / random all over the chromosomes:

```
3876
2000
10000
.
.
.
```

I need to use as many items as possible, in random locations.

Comment: Hi - could you provide `dput` of your data. As you question stands now, it is not reproducible.

Comment: Do you refer to this problem : [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem] ? If so, I don't really understand, in your question, what are the bins .. and what you mean by 'randomizing' .. could you provide an more precise example ?